# Previous cell value before some formula changed it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to use previous cell value before some fomula changed that value into something else?

For example:

```
A1=1.78541
A1=trunc(1.78541)
```

Is it still possible for me to use the previous value A1=1.78541?

I know that I can have 2 cells so I can use in this example both values, but that's not what I want. I want to have 1 cell and use both values: 1.78541 and trunc(1.78541).

Comment: A cell can only have one value.  Why is it important for you to have two values in one cell?

Comment: Can you please explain further what you want to do with the 2 different values? How would you want the result to look. What operations would you be applying to the 2 values in the same cell? From a high level view you could just join them as a string with a set delimiter and split them when your calling their values from another cell. Though it seems non trivial to just call the second value you want by just applying the TRUNC function on A1 as dokaspar is suggesting. Hopefully with some more details of your intentions, more suggestions will follow. Cheers,

Comment: Well, I need this for some physics report, in laboratory we measured some things and now we need to do calculation using those measurements. Every measurement has its own error that needs to be maximized (for example, if error is 0.25, maximized error should be 0.3). In reports we should only have maximized errors in column (because we have a lot of measurements and each one has it own error). Now, the column with errors should have only maximized errors, but I need errors that are not maximized so I can do calculations of something else. I made function in VBA that performs maximizing.

Comment: I actualy don't need function trunc. That was only example...

Answer (score 1):

Is this doable on a limited scale. Yes. Is it recommended? No. I understand your dilemma (math, logic and canonical practises vs. bat-crap-crazy ideas) and have run into enough idiotic requests from people with brand new MBAs on their wall that I would like offer up a method that you *could* use to retain the underlying cell value's five place decimal precision while showing only a truncated (*not* rounded) value with three decimal places.

The reason this can only be accomplished on a limited scale is that you will need to create a custom number format for every different value. There are a limited number of placeholders for custom number formats and if the values change often, you will run of of available space to create new ones.

For purposes of demonstration, I'll write the VBA into a public sub that processes any cell or group of cells selected.

```
Sub Display_Not_Truncate()
    On Error GoTo Fìn
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim rng As Range
    With Selection
        For Each rng In Selection
            If IsNumeric(rng) Then
                rng.NumberFormat = _
                  Replace(Replace(Application.RoundDown(rng.Value2, 3), "0", "\0"), ".", "\.") 'have to escape reserved characters like zeros and decimal points as literals
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Select any cell or cells to receive this treatment and run the macro. If the values change, their underlying value will change but not the displayed value unless you rerun the macro.

[image: Display not truncate]

You can see in the formula bar that the underlying value for A2 (the one used for calculation) is *1.78541* but the displayed value is *1.785*. The custom number format for that particular cell was `1\.785`. The underlying values of the cells in column A are shown in column B. Columns C and D demonstrate the differences between using the true value with a truncated display and actually using the truncated value.

With regard to the limited number of custom number formats: this is one of those *Limited by available memory* things. I ran out of available formats at ~175 custom number formats while I was creating and testing this. The custom number formats are retained by the individual workbook and are not global across all Excel workbooks.

There is a VBA command for deleting custom number formats but you have to know the format before you can use it. Example:

```
ThisWorkbook.DeleteNumberFormat NumberFormat:="1\.785"
```

I know of no way to tell if any particular custom number format is actually being used or not beyond cycling through every cell in the workbook and examining what is being used in that cell. I suppose Find ► Choose format from cell could help.

So yes, it is doable; just not recommended. If this is for a client, make sure that they know (in writing!) that this is counter to accepted worksheet and accounting practises and that the implementation is not only limited in scope, but has serious problems with keeping changing values updated.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
A1=1.78541
A2=trunc(A1)
```

Now you can work with A2

Comment: Thanks for answering, I know I can do that, but I already said that doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use number formatting to display a value, but calculations are performed on the underlying value.
Another option, if that is not feasible, is to have two sheets, (e.g. named "Raw" and "Trunc"), in which you store raw data in the Raw sheet, and formulas in the Trunc sheet, e.g.

```
=Trunc(Raw!A1)
```

or VBA to write explicit values to the Trunc sheet.
e.g. on the Raw sheet event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trunc").Range(Target.Range.Address).Value = int(Target.value)
End Sub
```

Comment: How did you get `Worksheetfunction.Trunc` working? I've always had trouble with that.

Comment: `Int(...)` will only pull out the whole number. You need to append with a truncated result from VBA's [MOD function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) with some math. (don't take this as a diss, just want to get the best answer posts)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the answer, I will think of a way to rewrite.   Question comes down to "I want to have 1 cell and use both values: 1.78541 and trunc(1.78541)."  Having both the original value and modified value, one on each sheet, will achieve this.  Additionally, can you explain the difference between Trunc() in Excel and int() in VBA?